# Construct infinitely many differentiable functions $f$, that satisfy $f'(x) = 3(f(x))^{2/3}$ and $f(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Construct infinitely many differentiable functions $f$, that satisfy $f'(x) = 3(f(x))^{2/3}$ and $f(0) = 0$.

It seems that we must solve this so we can integrate to get $\displaystyle \int f'(x) dx = f(x) + C =  \int{3(f(x))^{2/3}}dx$. Then I am not sure how to simply the integral on the left but we can solve for $C$. We must have that $C = 0$ and thus $f(x) = \displaystyle \int{3(f(x))^{2/3}}dx$. I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: The question title started out correctly ("Construct **infinitely many** differentiable functions..."), but after editing ("Construct **infinitely** differentiable functions...") seriously mis-matches the question's intent. That aside, the points are: 1. You can't usefully integrate both sides of your ODE; instead, separate variables, then integrate. 2. Your ODE with initial value has non-unique solutions, which can be "patched" in infinitely many distinct ways, as in Alex M.'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $-\infty \le a \le 0 \le b \le \infty$ and let $$f_{a, b} (x) = \left\{ \begin{eqnarray} (x-a)^3 &,& x < a \\ 0 &,& a \le x \le b \\ (x-b)^3 &,& b < x \end{eqnarray} \right. .$$ Then $$f_{a, b} '(x) = \left\{ \begin{eqnarray} 3(x-a)^2 &,& x < a \\ 0 &,& a \le x \le b \\ 3(x-b)^2 &,& b < x \end{eqnarray} \right. \ = \ 3 f_{a, b} (x) ^{\frac 2 3}$$ and $f_{a, b} (0) = 0$. Since there are infinitely many such $a, b$, there will be infinitely many distinct solutions $f_{a, b}$.

(In particular, when $a=b=0$ one gets $f(x) = x^3$.)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{3f^{2/3}(x)}dx=\int1dx$$
$$f^{1/3}(x)=x+C$$
$$f(x)=(x+C)^3$$
This can break down at $f(x)=0$.  At some point, the function can change from $f(x)=0$ to $f(x)=(x+C)^3$, and remain differentiable.

Comment: Why does $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{3f^{2/3}(x)}dx=\int1dx$$
$$f(x)=(x+C)^3?$$

Comment: "This can break down at $f(x)=0$.  At some point, the function can change from $f(x)=0$ to $f(x)=(x+C)^3$, and remain differentiable." I am not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: First, I divided by $f(x)^{2/3}$, which doesn't work at $f=0$.  Second, how can $f(x)=0$ sometimes, and $f(x)=(x+C)^3$ sometimes, and still be differentiable?

Comment: But the question gives us that $f(0) = 0$. How can you assume not? Also I think the $+3$ is a typo.